# fork() and execve() efficiency

Tags: memory, fork, stack

In terms of memory allocation efficiency is it right to say that after a `fork()` in the code of the child if I execute a program with `execve()` this would be more efficient than the same program executed without `execve()` because the child won't have allocated the stack and heap of the father but only is own?

Naife example:

without execve

```
 [..some father code...]
int i;
if(!fork()) {
 sum() //from an #include "porg.h"
}
```

with execve

```
 [..some father code...]

if(!fork()) {
 execve("sum", NULL, NULL); //sum is a program which executes i=2+3
}
```

The second in terms of memory allocation is better?
Is it better to replace the entire virtual address space of my process or it is better to get running the mentioned code with a call to a function in another program which is included with #include "prog" in terms of number of number of operations done by the so and in terms of the memory carried behind during the execution of the program?

Comment: Umm... They do two completely different things...

Comment: you might instead compare `fork`, `vfork`, `clone` (on linux), or `posix_spawn` to one another; the `exec*` routines are different

Comment: @StephenKitt edited

Comment: `i = 2+3` and `"sum"` are again two different things. what is the actual problem here?

Comment: @thrig what i meant to say was that sum would be a program which executes i = 2+3, i wanted to understand if making it with execve would allocate less memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not right to assume so.  Neither `sum` nor the fork child use the heap explicitly.  But in `sum`, the C runtime might initialize some heap structures at program start.  There's a similar possibility for the stack.

However this is a reasonable question to think about.  If the parent is also modifying memory while the child runs, the child will be hosting copies of all the modified memory (copy-on-write).  Often the child is performing a sub-task and only uses a subset of that data.

It's possible for it to be significant with a larger parent process and longer-running child process.

Comment: edited maybe is more clear what i mean

Comment: @ZenoRaiser i'm not getting anything different from the edit.  I suppose my answer is "it depends, **might go either way**, and if you're concerned about efficiency then the most important thing is to measure it", combined with: it's really hard to imagine it making much of a difference in the example you gave (child is not long-running, and you don't seem worried about the parent being large). I think it works out as a don't-care, if we're not missing anything important.

Answer (score 2):

The code inside the `if` in your first snippet contains one addition and one assignment. That's about as simple as anything can be, it would  compile into about two instructions in machine code.

In the second one, there's a bunch of arguments loaded and pushed to the stack, a function call, some internal processing by libc, which involves moving the arguments to the correct places for a system call, and then the system call itself.

The system call requires a switch to kernel mode (with whatever cost that entails, depends on the system), a lookup in the kernel to find what system call to actually process and then executing the program `sum`. Executing the program requires finding the file that contains the program, loading that into memory (possibly waiting for the disk), interpreting the ELF headers to know where in memory to put each part of the program, setting up some memory mappings, probably page tables and so...

I assume you get the idea.

Comment: edited maybe is more clear what i mean